# Changing the color of the SearchView in android

Tags: android, searchview

So my app has a dark background all over,
`#272822` And i want to use the SearchView,
But the issue with the SearchView is the search icon on it is also dark (almost black) so it is not visible clearly. How can i change the color of this icon and also the color of the text in the SearchView ?

```
<SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the searchview by this view and add android:theme with the name of the one below

do this with your search view :

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="146dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="173dp"
        android:theme="@style/search"/>
```

and create style.xml with this in it :

```
<style name="search" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

i hope this help

Comment: Awesome! Worked Perfectly. Can you just tell me why do we select Theme.Holo ? and what happens if instead of android.support.v7.widget.SearchView is do just SearchView ?

Comment: For the holo theme you can take it off it was just for me.

And if I remember correctly if we use the classic search view the color changes will not happen.